# Why is the Browser displaying different HTML to that returned with BeautifulSoup and Requests?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

**The Situation**

I was working on a beginner project where I basically search for something and my Python program should open up that particular Google search page and also open up the first 5 search results, in different tabs.

For opening the webpage/tabs I am using the Webbrowser module and for finding which Search Results URLs need to be opened up in the other tabs, I was using Beautiful Soup to find the link.

```py
    args = ('+'.join(args)).lower()
    google_url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={args}'
    webbrowser.open(google_url)                             #Opening the first Google search window
    res = requests.get(google_url,timeout=5)
    soup = BS(res.text,'lxml')
    
    print(soup.prettify())                                 # HTML Code I used to select the tags
    
    tab_urls = []                                           # Making a list of all URLs to be opened up
    
    for data in soup.select("div[class = 'ZINbbc xpd O9g5cc uUPGi']"):
        a_tag = data.select_one('a[href]')
        if a_tag:
            if a_tag['href'].startswith('/url?q='):             # Figured that when HREF starts with '/url?' it will link to another website
                new_url = a_tag['href'].replace('/url?q=','')   # String formatting/operations to get the Tab link
                new_url = new_url.split('%')[0]                 # String formatting/operations to get the Tab link
                new_url = new_url.split('&')[0]                 # String formatting/operations to get the Tab link
                tab_urls.append(new_url)
    
    for url in range(min(len(tab_urls),3)):
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(tab_urls[url])                  # Opening up the Tabs
```

**The Problem:**

The code above works and my program is working, however while searching for the exact tag using Inspect element I noticed that the HTML code source is different from the HTML that was returned to me on
soup.prettify().

**The Question:**

How is this the case, what is the reason that BeautifulSoup is reading different HTML to that within the browser from the same URL?

Comment: Many webpages nowadays render their contents dynamically with javascripts.  Unfortunately BeautifulSoup doesn't do the rendering and therefore cannot access these types of contents that you are able to view in your browser.  You'll need to use a different library like `selenium` to parse these rendered contents.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as @r.ook.  Look up and install `request-html` library.  It will get and render Javascript page code in 3 lines.

Comment: @Windstorm1981 I was going to recommend [`requests-html`](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) as well.  Good back-end alternative if you don't want to run `selenium` headless.

Comment: Okay yes thank you. I will look at both selenium and requests-html. Is there any way to figure out if a particular page is rendering it's contents dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

In this case (*the data you're trying to parse*), the page doesn't render dynamically via JavaScript as [r.ook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61064181/webscraping-with-beautiful-soup-requests-2-diff-html-from-the-browser-and-requ#comment108031511_61064181) mentioned, thus there's no need in using `selenium` or `requests-html` since the content you're trying to parse doesn't locate somewhere in the `<scrip>` tags, if so, that's probably mean that the content is rendered via JavaScript.

The most often problem is that there's no `user-agent` being passed into request headers thus when no `user-agent` is specified while using `requests` library, it defaults to [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and Google understands that it's a bot/script, blocks a request and you receive a different HTML with different `CSS` selectors. [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

Pass `user-agent`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

requests.get('URL', headers=headers)
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

params = {
  'q': 'how to create minecraft server',
  'gl': 'us',
  'hl': 'en',
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# [:3] - first 3 results
# container with needed data: title, link, snippet, etc.
for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc')[:3]:
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  print(link, sep='\n')

----------
'''
https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360058525452-How-to-Setup-a-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Server
https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server
https://www.idtech.com/blog/creating-minecraft-server
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to spend time trying to bypass blocks from Google if the problem is not only to pass `user-agent` in requests headers, and there's no need to maintain the parser over time if something in the HTML will be changed.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "how to create minecraft server",
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "us",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"][:3]:
  print(result["link"], sep="\n")


----------
'''
https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360058525452-How-to-Setup-a-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Server
https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server
https://www.idtech.com/blog/creating-minecraft-server
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.